# find and copy today's date xml files to another directory in unix

Tags: bash, unix, file-io

`Dir1`  and `Dir2` are directories. There are about 4000 files in /home/test/

Below is my file structure, `/home/test/` has these files and directories:

```
 test1.xml
 a2.xml
 4000.xml
 Dir1
 Dir2
```

I want to copy all the .xml files which are modified or `created in last 24hrs` from

source: `/home/test/`

destination: `/home/test/Dir2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`find /home/test/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.xml' -mtime -1 -print0 | while read -d '' -r file; do cp $file /home/test/Dir2/$(basename $file); done`